# Not available with this estimation method (ARMA ML) error message in eviews

Tags: hypothesis-testing, arima, autocorrelation, eviews, error-message

I tried a Breusch–Godfrey LM test on an ARMA Maximum Likelihood model in eviews and I got the following error message:

> Not available with this estimation method  (ARMA ML).

I re-estimated the equation using Conditional Least Squares and the LM test worked just fine. My question is what is the theoretical reason this test doesn't work on a ARMA ML model?